# Wordpress page not showing up - replaced with last 10 posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields, slug

I've been working hard at a system to upload articles to. Specifically via a custom post who's URL changes based on an ACF selection field.

I've had great success, with users here helping me on the final push to fix 404 errors. but now, it seems that I'm stuck again. The parent pages seem to be uneditable, forcing the last 10 posts to show.

Here's the setup. I have a Page who's parenting structure is Community => Articles => Theories. the url is **example.com/community/articles/theory/**

When I visit that URL, it only displays the last 10 posts. Not custom posts, just regular posts.

The code I have to change permalinks for the Articles custom post type is this:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%category_type%', '([^&]+)' );
register_post_type(
    'articles', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Articles',
            'singular_name' => 'Article',
            'add_new' => 'Add new article',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit article',
            'new_item' => 'New article',
            'view_item' => 'View article',
            'search_items' => 'Search articles',
            'not_found' => 'No articles found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No articles found in Trash',
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'community/articles/%category_type%'),
        'menu_icon' => "dashicons-groups",
        'capability_type' => array('article','articles'),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    )
);
```

---

```
function rem_articles_rewrite( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $ptype=get_post_type($post);
        if($ptype=="articles"){

            $category=get_field('category',$post->ID);
            if( $category ){
                return str_replace( '%category_type%' , $category , $post_link );
            }
        }
    }
return $post_link;
}
```

That ensures articles appear at, for example, **example.com/community/articles/theory/-ARTICLE_NAME-/**. But I fear it's also locking the **example.com/community/articles/theory/** page, so I am unable to edit this page via the regular Page section. Somehow, it's fallback isn't a 404, but the last 10 posts of the site.

The page **example.com/community/articles/** seems unaffected by whatever's going wrong. it's only the direct child of that page that are affected. Further children of the child pages (The custom post articles themselves) show up with no problem.

Is there anything that immediately jumps out at anyone? Something I've overlooked?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the rewrite rules generated with the post type- they're a bit greedy and are capturing those requests. WordPress is trying to query for a matching `category_type`, which isn't actually an object type, and in the absence of any other valid query argument, it runs the main blog query.

You could manually generate the post type rewrite rules in a way that is less greedy, or you can add a rule that just overrides them in the case where `ARTICLE_NAME` isn't present:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^community/articles/([^/]*)?/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=community/articles/$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

When dealing with rewrites, I recommend the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin, which will give you a new menu item in admin under Tools where you can plug in URLs and see how they are matching to rewrite rules and parsing to query vars.

Comment: Ah, that's absolutely perfect! Solved the problem right away. Thanks!

Interesting plugin. I'll use it, see if it helps in future. I don't think I'm quite up to the challenge of figuring out this PHP code myself (I'm still very much a monkey see, monkey do level of PHP coding), but at the very least, it should help the next time I have issues like this.

Thanks again for the help! :)